# Error: Input("InsufficientBalance") when running benchmark

Tags: benchmarking

Trying to benchmark an extrinsic, but I keep getting error:

```
./target/release/rmrk-substrate benchmark --pallet pallet-rmrk-core --extrinsic 'create_collection'
Error: Input("InsufficientBalance")
```

Here's the code:

```
benchmarks! {
    create_collection {
        let origin: T::AccountId = whitelisted_caller();
        T::Currency::make_free_balance_be(&origin, T::Currency::minimum_balance() * 20_000_000u32.into());
    }: _(RawOrigin::Signed(origin), bvec![0u8; 20], Some(5), bvec![0u8; 15])
    verify {
    }
    impl_benchmark_test_suite!(Template, crate::mock::ExtBuilder::default().build(whitelisted_caller()), crate::mock::Test);
}
```

I've tried various manipulations of the `T::Currency::make_free_balance_be` line, without success.  The code compiles successfully with `cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks`, but still fails on this extrinsic.

This is my first attempt at benchmarking.  Likely something simple.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it was due to insufficient balance.
I needed to change the code to:

```rust
T::Currency::make_free_balance_be(&origin, DepositBalanceOf::<T>::max_value());
```

Where `DepositBalanceOf` is (for me at least):

```rust
type DepositBalanceOf<T> = <<T as pallet_uniques::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;
```

Comment: In my case, I also needed to remember to use the Currency trait. For some reason, it did not error out.